# PHP echo a returned value from another function in the same class

Tags: php, function

I'm having trouble to echo a result from a function within a function in the same class.

```
class className 
    {
         function first_function()
         {
             echo "Here it is: " . $this->second_function('test');
         }

         function second_function($string)
         {
             return $string;
         }
    }
```

That returns only:

```
Here it is:
```

Echoing the $string in my second_function() results in:

```
testHere it is:
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, it's work. What you have error message?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: I'm guessing it should echo *Here it is: test* ... and I can't immediately see a reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: @Iwan – no error messages. the second_function returns nothing...

Comment: It's normal behavior, if you echo $string in your second function, the second function is called before the result of the first is sent. However the result should be "testHere it is : test"

Maybe you replace return with echo, which is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @Chay22 expected output: Here it is: test

Comment: It looks to me like you simplified the code but didn't test the simplified code, because the code you posted works just fine. So probably you accidentally removed the part of your code which is causing your problem! Please include more code in the example until you get the same error when you actually test the example. I guess the error actually lies around the part where you *call* the second function, or more precisely, process its return value.

Comment: Just like, [Here it is: test](https://eval.in/573773). Either you need to post the actual code or take a nap as you might've been tired now :D

Comment: @Klass please check what you get `echo $obj->second_function('test');` (before you edit you question, you haven't `;` after `return $string`, please check it's too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class className 
    {
         function first_function()
         {
             echo "Here it is: " . $this->second_function('test');
         }

         function second_function($string)
         {
             return $string;
         }
    }


    $obj = new className();
   $a=  $obj->first_function();
   echo $a;
```

Comment: it's woking fine then what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

as @cherryTD mentioned, I did simplify the code. I see why it didn't work. Posting it here so it might help someone else. 
The second function is a recursive function and that didn't work:

```
function second_function($var,$cnt) {
    [database query]
    if(result) {
        $cnt++;
        $this->second_function($var, $cnt);
    } else {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

But this does work:

```
function second_function($var,$cnt) {
    [database query here]
    if(result) {
        $cnt++;
        return $this->second_function($var, $cnt);
    } else {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

A **return** was needed when calling the function from within itself.

so:

```
$this->second_function($var, $cnt);
```

had to be:

```
return $this->second_function($var, $cnt);
```

Thank you for the responses, everyone.